# js method in Application.js not being called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I put the following method in my application.js file.

```
var formhandler = function() {
    var submit, isSubmit = false;
    submit = function(){
                // flop and return false once by the use of operator order.
    return isSubmit != (isSubmit = true);
    };
    return {
       submit: submit
       };
}(); // <-- use direct invcation to keep the internal variables "static"
```

It works fine if I write it directly in the header section of the form. However when I put it in the application.js file it is not being called or found.

How should I call functions that are in applcation.js.

Also I have the following in the header of the layout.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => true, :recursive => true %>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an alert or console.log to your application.js file to verify that it is being loaded?

Comment: I did that and yes its working in the application.js. Now I just realize that its not really doing what it is supposed to do which is prevent the user from submitting multiple times

Comment: Have you tried adding console.log(isSubmit != (isSubmit = true)) to your submit function to verify that the return value is correct. If it is, your problem could be how you attach the handler to the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t fully understand your question,so I may be wrong, but as a remark:

here you always return false:

```
return isSubmit != (isSubmit = true);
```

I think it should be

```
return isSubmit != (isSubmit == true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried that as well and it seems to still allow the user to submit many times.